# How to display DOI in reference list with natbib?

Tags: natbib, doi

I am using natbib and am trying to get the doi in the reference list as well. But whatever I try, it just won´t show up. I got it to work earlier. For some reason it is not working now.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apacite}    
%\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{natbib}     
\usepackage{hyperref} 
%\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi: #1}}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mastBIB_3,method}         
\end{document}
```

I tried a combination of all the commands above and I just can´t find the problem. Thanks in advance. I know that other people have already asked this question. But none of the answers helped.

Comment: have any of your references include a DOI? there's an extra field for that called "doi = <code>" inside the bibitem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You mustn't load both the `apacite` and the `natbib` citation management packages. If you do do, it shouldn't be necessary to load the `doi` package. Make these changes and perform a full recompile cycle (latex-bibtex-latex-latex).

Comment: Incidentally, does your editor really use `latin1` input encoding? I suggest switching to `utf8`.

Comment: deleting apacite did the trick. I don´t know, why I didn´t see I had not uncommented it. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Mico I tried to run it in [uft8], but can´t get that to work. But it runs fine with what I have now.

Comment: "can't get that to work" isn't very specific. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I tried to change it to utf8 again. For some reason it works now. However, I just realised, that the year does not show up in my references. Is there a way that I can actually get all entries of the bibfile to show up in the references??

Comment: Yes: Add the instruction `\nocite{*}` and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Hi, I tried to run \nocite{*}. But it still does not give me the year. Does it have anything to do with the bibliography style?? When I use abbrevnat, my bibliography does not show up at al. I really apreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

use the note field instead of the doi field:
...
note = {ABC/123...},
...

This is not necessarily conformal to journal style, but the DOI shows up and the editing staff at the journal should be able to put the DOI into the right format. It is not necessarily the user's fault that the DOI does not show up. It might be that the style definition file of the press house is buggy (have the problem with ACS Paragon).

Cheers,
dko

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The field does not seem to be the problem as stated in the comments. Note: article is no journal class.